# Correct structure of a data science project: keeping as functions versus object-oriented framework

Tags: python

I'm working on a data science project that involves data ingestion, cleaning and various aggregations and functions of timeseries equipment data primarily using Pandas. I began the project just writing various functions from the ground up, but am now at a point where I need to make critical decisions about the codebase structure before it gets out of hand.

I don't have much experience creating an object-oriented framework, but suspect that this would be the correct way to go in my case. However, I want to use best practices and introduce OOP, but only if it actually provides utility.

Here's a general overview of what the codebase does (with a reference to the dummy classes I created in the dummified code that follows:

1. Ingests data from a specified dir (GetData class)
2. Performs data cleaning (GetData class)
3. Creates a set of new variables at the same granular timestamp level. What makes this tricky is that are functions that create 1 variable for the entire dataset, but also functions that create 1 value for each piece of specific equipment type (PreppedData class)
4. Group raw data by different temporal aggregations - year, year/month, year/week, year/dayofyear/hour (GroupedObject class)
5. Concatenate both the raw data and grouped raw data into a list and then deploy the same set of functions on that list (AnalyzedData)
6. Write outputs from step 5 to Excel tabs. I don't have a class for this - not sure whether this should just be a side-effect in every detailed function

The `DataAnalysis` class is a bit complex because we need functions that know whether the object is at the granular level (and thus doesn't require an apply statement to perform an operation on the groups) or not.  There will be a large collection of different methods here.

For example, in addition to the weighted mean that I have in the code, here is another ones I have to - identify pieces of equipment whose z-score is less than -2 st. devs from the mean compared to other equiment of that type.  Then do an aggregation on that and identify the pieces of equipment that have consecutive outlier zscores for n consecutive time periods.  This is just an example, it doesn't really matter what the analyses would be, but the structure would be the same.

```
import pandas as pd

class GetData(imp_format):
    def __init__(self):
        if imp_format=='csv': 
        files = glob.glob(path+'*.csv')
        for i in files:
            df = pd.read_csv(#etc.
            df_lst.append(df)
        elif imp_format=='excel':
            # similar process
                
        comb_data = pd.concat(df_lst, axis=0)
        self.data = comb_data
                
    def clean_data():
        pass

class PreppedData():
    # methods to take raw data and create new fields with same time aggregation
    def method_1():
        # returns 1 new variable for each timestamp
        
    def method_2(self, equipment_type_var_names)
        # returns 1 value for each timestamp for each specific equipment type
        # so timestamp in index, and columns would be discrete pieces of equipment
        
    # etc.
        
class GroupedObject():
    def __init__(self, input_data):
        hourly = input_data.groupby(input_data.index.year, input_data.index.dayofyear, input_data.index.hour)
        daily = input_data.groupby(input_data.index.year, input_data.index.dayofyear)
        # etc
        self.data_lst = [input_data, hourly, daily, #etc.]
        

class DataAnalysis():
    def __init__(self, input_lst):
        self.data_lst = input_lst

    # calculates weighted mean of var_name with weight_var as the weight
    def weighted_mean_helper(df, var_name, weight_var):
    
    # calculates weighted mean of every variable in the var_name list with weight_var as the weight
    def weighted_mean_apply_helper(df, var_lst, weight_var)
    
    def calc_custom_weighted_mean_overall(input_list, mean_var, weight_var):
        result_lst = []
        for i in input_list:
            if type(i)==pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy:   # note that this would give error, not sure how to check if object is df groupby
                temp = df.apply(weighted_mean_helper, var_name=mean_var, weight_var=weight_var)
                result_lst.append()
            else:
                temp = weighted_mean_helper(df, var_name, weight_var)
                result_lst.append(temp)
    
    
    def calc_custom_weighted_mean_by_equipment(input_list, equipment_type_var_names, weight_var):
        result_set = []
        for i in input_list:
            if type(i)==pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy::
                temp = i.apply(weighted_mean_apply_helper, var_lst = equipment_type_var_names, weight_var=weight_var)
                # consolidate all results into a dataframe
                res_cons = ###
                result_set.append(res_cons)
            else:
                for j in equipment_type_var_names:
                    temp = weighted_mean_helper(df[[j, weight_var]])
                    result_set.append(temp)
```

Although this structure seems roughly ok, except for the `GetData` class, which could serve as a parent class for subclasses that are specific to the api of the datasource, I'm not able to articulate to myself why I shouldn't just keep this structure in function form without adding classes, similar to how I have it now.

Comment: I think the grouping seems hard to justify, because it's very superficial. You still just have a bundle of functions, just called in a different way. Take a look at `AnalyzedData` for example. For one, it doesn't model analyzed data, so it's name is totally wrong. From the looks of it, it's more of a `CustomWeightCalculator`. It also appears that many of its methods take a lot of similar parameters. Perhaps those should be instance variables of the calculator objects.

Comment: `class GetData(imp_format)` doesn't make sense. Did you mean `def __init__(self, imp_format)` instead?

Comment: @Alexander, yes, I meant `def __init__(self, imp_format)`.  Regarding `AnalyzeData`, you're right, the name should be `AnalyzeData`, since it contains methods that analyze it.  The `WeightWalculator` is just one out of many many methods that would go here, so it's just an example.  Are you suggesting that I create a class for a calculator object and then pass different parameters to it?  If I do this, then I will have many if statements in `__init__`, since the actual functions will be doing different things.  Thanks

Comment: "the name should be `AnalyzeData`" no actually, it shouldn't. Class names should be nouns, or noun phrases. They models "things", not "actions". Method names, on the other hand, should be verbs or verb phrases. They model the actions that the nouns (objects, instances of classes) can perform.

Comment: "Are you suggesting that I create a class for a calculator object and then pass different parameters to it?" Probably, yeah. From what I can tell, all of the public methods of your current `AnalyzedData` class take an `input_list`. Perhaps that should be a property of the calculator: One is instantiated for a particular `input_list`, and then multiple calculates can be made on it, in the various methods. It's hard to tell for sure, because I don't know your business domain.

Comment: I hadn't included instantiation of the object with a list in `DataAnalysis` (let's call it that for now), but basically that was my intent.  I added another example of a method in my original post, but I don't think you need the domain to get a sense of the structure.  It appears I may be on the right track - I put all of my methods that analyze the data into that class.  How should I deal with writing to csv - should I create a separate class for this or put it somewhere else?

Comment: I think it would help if you took a step back and tried to understand the motivation behind classes. Just moving free functions into classes doesn't really achieve anything, and it's not really "object oriented". Sure, classes bring some benefit w.r.t. code organization and grouping similar operations together, kind of like folders on a file system, but it's more than that. The key aspect of object orientation is polymorphism. New classes makes sense to be introduced where there are new responsibilities, especially where you might want to pick from one of several possible implementations.

Comment: For example, your program probably currently hardcodes the fact that input is read from a CSV, and that results are written back out to another CSV. But what if you wanted to take input from a Web API, and write it out results to a database? Having a `DataSetImporter` and `DataSetExporter` classes, each with a CSV-specific subclass, lets you write modular code, that can rely on polymorphism to pick the right thing to do. Case in point: the `imp_format` parameter of `GetData` makes it very clear that `GetData` is actually two classes trying to escape. ...

Comment: ... There should be an `ExcelDataSetImporter`, and a `CSVDataSetImporter`, both of which conform to the same interface, so that they're modular, so you can swap out one for another as yo uneed.

Comment: You write that the key aspect of object orientation is polymorphism.   I read a bit about it, and think I understand the basics, but don't quite see exactly how whether I need polymorphism should be the deciding criteria for whether or not I use classes.  So we can have a different classes for animals with each having a `make_noise` method.  Except that for `class Fish`, the method is empty.  So are you saying that I should only use classes if I have 2 classes where I will use methods with the same name, but slightly different actions?  If not, should I just keep code in functions then?

Comment: Feel free to write response as answer to the question, so that I can mark it.  Thanks

Comment: It's kind of hard to summarize what I said into a single coherent answer. "So are you saying that I should only use classes if I have 2 classes where I will use methods with the same name, but slightly different actions?" Not necessarily. Classes/objects play a lot of different roles. The main one that made them "rise to popularity" is their ability to act as "seems" in a program, where one module boundary can end and another can start, in a way that makes the modules swappable. I was using this as a motivation for why you should split `GetData` into two classes, one for CSV, one for Excel.

Comment: A second purpose of classes is the one I mentioned earlier, about grouping related functionality together, to help in organizing it. That might motivate some of your free functions to be moved into classes. Another purpose of classes also arises when you have multiple functions that take a similar group of parameters. These parameters probably represent "something". That "something" can  be extracted into a class, converting those params into fields. That class can then contain those methods, which no longer need to take those similar fields as parameters, they just access them on `self`

Comment: Like @Alexander said, people don't use classes because it automagically makes your code better; people use classes because it helps **you** to organize your own code. It's easier for the human mind to grasp what a huge codebase is doing if you abstract some of its functionality into small objects that have a good name and purpose. If you can't organize your expected data workflow using a blank sheet of paper and pen, you can't expect classes to do that for you.